# localhost not found while running dotnet core apps

Tags: .net-core

I recently started learning dotnet core, I downloaded and run dotnet sdk then i created console app using `dotnet new console -o myApp` then i executed `dotnet run` command i got output helloworld i thought everything working fine
then i created webapi, not modified any file and executed dotnet run got msg listening to port 5000 whenever i am trying to open `localhost:5000` i am getting localhost not found..I searched online but didn't get any solution  pls help me..

Comment: try using your machine IP address

Comment: @ Nitin Sawant, getting site can't be reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect after navigating to localhost:5000?

I'm sure your API is fine if you did everything as you described. Do you have a default `ValuesController` or something other with sample action methods?

Look at screenshot where I have run .net core api project and then I sent request to the `Get()` method by using Postman

[image: ValuesControler]